# Optional ManyToOne association in Symfony/Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm currently working in a new version of a project that contains an existing database, so I need to create entities trying to minify the database changes. My main problem is I want to create an optional association between two Entities but we I run *doctrine:scheme:update* command, it throws me the next error:

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE table_A ADD CONSTRAINT 
FK_AAB363B1DD3B1998 FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES table_B 
(id)': SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update 
a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`#sql-7d0_1881`, CONSTRAINT 
`FK_AAB363B1DD3B1998` FOREIGN KEY (`b_id`) REFERENCES 
`table_B` (`id`))


[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child 
row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`#sql-7d0_1881`, CONSTRAINT 
`FK_AAB363B1DD3B1998` FOREIGN KEY (`b_id`) REFERENCES 
`table_B` (`id`))
```

As you can see in the error, Class A has a property that contains an object on Entity B. This association must be unidirectional.

When I declare this type of association, I'm using this code:

```
/**
 * @var B
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="B")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="b_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
```

I want to make this association optional because this field is not required at all.

I've tried using *nullable* attribute, but reading Doctrine docs, it seems its default value is true, so it should work for me, but for any reason it doesn't.

I would appreciate any advice, code snippet or anything you can tell me about this issue.

Regards and thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

I already checked this column has NULL attribute:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiNNP.png

Comment: Did you make sure that table column in database has `NULL` attribute (as opposed to `NOT NULL`)?

Comment: @jperovic Yes, I already checked that first before post the question. Do you have something else in mind?

Comment: This is a long shot but did you mess with rows in `table_b` (as deleted) while foreign key check was off? Also, check if columns types are exactly the same (not just type-name, but length as well)

Comment: Did you try to add nullable here : **@ORM\JoinColumn(name="b_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)** ?
Did you try to remove the relations on the db (not the data, just relation index), and run **php/console doctrine:schema:update --force** again ?

Comment: @jperovic Hi, I didn't modify any data in table_b. The thing is there are a lot of records with 'b_id' empty, so they don't have a valid id for an existing B record, that's why I want to make it optional.

Comment: @ThomasPiard I've tried both things with no success. It seems Doctrine wants to make that field required... :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running `doctrine:scheme:update` run `doctrine:scheme:update --dump-sql`

Then run manually the output SQL code and ignore the irrelevant *ALTER TABLE table_A ADD CONSTRAINT* commands

Comment: Thank you @skafandri, this solution would help, but I would like to set up correctly the association between A and B. Let's see if somebody finds out the right approach to this issue, but thank you for answer anyway.